# Asking solutions for the integral equations

Tags: integral-equations

This is from Berkeley Problems in Mathematics, Spring 86. It asks for $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, find all solutions of the following two equations:

$$\phi(x)=e^{x}+\lambda\int^{x}_{0}e^{x-y}\phi(y)dy; \psi(x)=e^{x}+\lambda\int^{1}_{0}e^{x-y}\psi(y)dy$$

My thought is to take the derivative, thus we have $\frac{d}{dx}\phi=e^{x}+\lambda\phi(x)$ because we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\lambda \int^{x}_{0}e^{x}/e^{y}\phi(y)dy=\lambda e^{x}/e^{x}\phi(x)=\lambda \phi(x)$$. And so is the equation for $\psi$ Thus the difference equation would be $$\frac{d}{dx}(\phi-\psi)=\lambda(\phi-\psi)$$ and implies $\phi-\psi=Ce^{\lambda x}$ for some $C$. But I do not know how to use this to solve the original equation. The seeming simple equation $$\frac{d}{dx}\phi=e^{x}+\lambda\phi(x)$$is also not easy to solve. I do not know how to treat the delay term $e^{x}$ or find a special solution for this.

Comment: Double-check your first derivative; it is incorrect.  Also, is there a typo in the question?  The two equations seem to be identical copies, making the problem very uninteresting.

Comment: There is typo as you can check here:http://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/Spring86.pdf But my derivative may be wrong as you said.

Comment: I double checked, and see no problem with the derivative. Yes it is an uninteresting problem to me...

Comment: The upper limit on the integral with the $\psi$ equation should be $1$, not $x$.

Comment: I get the differential equation $\phi' = (1+\lambda) \phi$. You differentiated incorrectly, the upper limit of integration is $x$, not a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $\phi(x)=e^{x}+\lambda\int^{x}_{0}e^{x-y}\phi(y) \,dy$ is $\phi'(x) = e^{x}+\lambda \phi(x) + \lambda\int^{x}_{0}e^{x-y}\phi(y)\, dy$,
or, more clearly, $\phi' = (1+\lambda) \phi$.

The derivative of $\psi(x)=e^{x}+\lambda\int^{1}_{0}e^{x-y}\psi(y) \, dy$ is $\psi'(x) = e^{x} +\lambda\int^{1}_{0}e^{x-y}\psi(y) \, dy$, o, more clearly, $\psi' = \psi$.

The solutions are $\phi(x) = \phi(0) e^{(1+\lambda) x}$, and $\psi(x) = \psi(0) e^x$.

Comment: I am confused, the equation is the same, why the derivative is different?

Comment: Sorry, I made the mistake of copying your equation text. The upper limit of integration on the $\psi$ integral is $1$, not $x$. I have fixed it. Look at the reference you provided more carefully.

Comment: Sorry, I made the mistake of copying down the wrong problem. I want to ask why we had the extra $\lambda\int^{x}_{0}e^{x-y}dy$ term in the derivative, it feels not needed.

Comment: I see..I see. The Leibniz formula.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you explain what garantees that you can differentiate the equations?  The problem does not say anything about their differentiability and I believe you would have to prove that first, no?

Comment: @TeXApprentice Since $\phi, \psi$ appear under an integral sign, there is an implicit assumption that they are integrable. It follows from the fixed point equations that they are continuous and again it follows that they are differentiable.